# Why does xterm's command line behave like this after changing the prompt?

Tags: prompt, tcsh

In my .cshrc file I have the following line:

```
set prompt="%B%n@%m [%d %T] (%h) %c3%#"
```

When I open an xterm, I see

```
user@host [Fri 13:37] (2) ~>0;238;0c
```

Why is *`0;238;0c`* there? I can't spot the error in my set prompt.

Comment: You also possibly set `precmd` in your `.cshrc`?

Comment: That looks a bit like what some terminal could return after you run `printf '\033[>c'`. Is `238` your version of `xterm`?

Comment: What's the output of `echotc me | sed -n l`?

Comment: 238 is my version of xterm. `printf '\033[>c'` outputs `^[[>0;238;0c` and `echotc me | sed -n l` outputs `\033[0m$`.

Comment: Now we need to figure out what sends `\033[>c`. or `\033[>0c`. How about `infocmp -x1 | grep '>0*c'` or `infocmp -xC1 | grep '>0*c'`? What's the operating system? Do you see the same after you run `setenv TERM vt100`?

Comment: Are you sure there's no `precmd` alias? What's the output of `alias | grep cmd`?

Comment: `infocmp -x1 | grep '>0*c'` returns nothing. `infocmp -xC1 | grep '>0*c'` returns `infocmp: xterm entry is 1051 bytes long`. The output of `alias | grep cmd` is nothing.

Comment: What OS is it? With [that old a version of xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_238), I don't expect it's Linux based, is it?

Comment: `NAME="SLES"
VERSION="11.4"
VERSION_ID="11.4"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:11:4"`

Comment: (you know it's eol, right?) Then can you run `strace -fs1000 -o strace.log tcsh`, exit tcsh after the issue has materialised and post the `strace.log` somewhere